# Walking OCaml tuples of arbitrary depth

Tags: ocaml, type-inference

I'm trying to understand better the OCaml type inference. I created this example:

```
let rec f t = match t with
    | (l,r) -> (f l)+(f r)
    | _ -> 1
```

and I want to apply it on any binary tuple (pair) with nested pairs, to obtain the total number of leafs. Example: f ((1,2),3)

The function f refuses to compile, because a contradiction in types at (f l): "This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type 'a * 'b".

Question: 'a being any type, could not also be a pair, or else be handled by the  _ case? Is any method to walk tuples of arbitrary depth without converting them to other data structures, such as variants?

PS: In C++ I would solve this kind of problem by creating two template functions "f", one to handle tuples and one other types.

Comment: What would `f`'s type be?

Comment: I think just 'a->int, so it can handle both pairs and other values...but it is just a thought.

Comment: If `t` has a completely unknown type (`'a`), then you can't pattern match on it.

Comment: And there isn't a possibility inside f to declare two auxiliary functions, one specialized for pairs and one without any specialization, and to call them specifically based on the f argument type? Anyway, thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to do this, although I wouldn't recommend it to a new user due to the resulting complexities. You should get used to writing regular OCaml first.

That said, you can walk arbitrary types in a generic way by capturing the necessary structure as a GADT. For this simple problem it is quite easy:

```
type 'a ty =
  | Pair : 'a ty * 'b ty -> ('a * 'b) ty
  | Other : 'a ty

let rec count_leaves : type a . a -> a ty -> int =
  fun a ty ->
    match ty with
    | Pair (ta, tb) -> count_leaves (fst a) ta + count_leaves (snd a) tb
    | Other -> 1
```

Notice how the pattern matching on the `a ty` here corresponds to the pattern matching on values in your (poorly typed) example function.

More useful functions could be written with a more complete type representation, although the machinery becomes heavy and complicated once arbitrary tuples, records, sum types, etc have to be supported.

Comment: After I posted my question I saw that my example was a case of "polymorphic recursion" (probably) and it seems that GADT can help the type inference with these cases. I will look more into this. Can you complete your answer with how count_leaves is called, because I tried with "count_leaves ((1,2),3)" and it returns a function, not the number of leaves?

Comment: You need to pass a GADT value as well: `count_leaves ((1, 2), 3) (Pair (Pair (Other, Other), Other)) => 3`.

Comment: (There's a proposal to add a kind of inference that will generate this kind of rather tedious GADT value for you, but that isn't in the language yet.)

Answer (score 3):

Any combination of tuples will have a value shape completely described by it's type (because there is no "choice" in the type structure) - hence the "number of leaves" question can be answered completely statically at compile-time. Once you have a function operating on such type - this function is fixed to operate on that specific type (and shape) only.

If you want to build a tree that can have different shapes (but same type - hence can be handled by same function) - you need to add variants to the mix, i.e. classic `type 'a tree = Leaf of 'a | Node of 'a tree * 'a tree`, or any other type that describes value with some dynamic "choice" of shape.